# When to save user data to disk?

Tags: node.js, database, hard-drive

I've been getting into web applications and node.js lately, and it's obvious that you should write user data to the disk, but when should I? It would be a bit overkill and very resource intensive to write to the disk every time data is updated, so when should you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend creating a temporary memory cache to store user data. (For actively connected users)

Read and write to this memory cache as needed to maintain user sessions / realtime functionality, then write to disk as necessary for persistent data. "Eventual persistence" is an option for avoiding writing to disk very often, but could lead to eventual issues if writes fail.